# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor - Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, constructor

I have the following model:

```
lza.models.Location = Backbone.Model.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("lzalocations")
});
```

And in another method that I call on clicking a button:

```
var p = new lza.models.Location();
```

In the console I see:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new lza.models.Location()')
```

These are in multiple javascript files, and I have made sure that the model.js file loads before the one that is trying to call it.

In my console I get the following:

```
lza                   #=> Object
lza.models            #=> Object
lza.models.Location   #=> undefined
lza.models.Location() #=> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new lza.models.Location()')
```

So I know that the namespacing isn't the problem, but why is the `Location` object undefined, and why am I getting this error.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `console.log` (or use a debugger) right before you call `Backbone.Model.extend` to make certain that's getting called?

Comment: huh, no I haven't tried that. That might just be the problem. Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Do you check `lza` name spacing? May be you declared it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was that the file that I downloaded for Backbone.localStorage was NOT a .js file, but actually a file that had the HTML of the page where I COULD download the .js file... Once I corrected it with the actual file, everything started working.

Thank you all.